# Equivalence of DATEADD in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query that I used to be able to run in SQL server but cannot in PostgreSQL. Can you provide a query that will do the same as I cannot use DATEADD for Postgres.

```
select *
from VTable
where join_date>='1/1/2020' and join_date<'1/1/2021'
and join_date>= DATEADD(day,-30, removed_date)
and lremoved = 1
and countryid = '100010'
order by join_date asc
```

Comment: When you looked up the [date/time functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html), nothing was an obvious thing to try?

Comment: I had no idea this page existed! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) you can add an integer to a `date` value which represents the number of days to add.

Also: ANSI date literals are preferred over locale specific date (or timestamp) values as they are  unambiguous.

```
select *
from VTable
where join_date >= date '2020-01-01'
  and join_date < date '2021-01-01'
  and join_date >= removed_date - 30
  and lremoved = 1
  and countryid = '100010'
order by join_date asc
```

If `join_date` is a `timestamp` rather than a `date`, use an interval:

```
  and join_date >= removed_date - interval '30 days'
```

The above is all standard ANSI SQL which Postgres happens to honor.

Comment: what if character = integer?

Comment: @oaker: sorry no idea what you mean. You can't compare a string with an integer. If `countryid` is an integer, use `countryid = 100010`